# What Function/Equation for Rounding Down by using Ranges in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, rounding, ceil

We have a new program in our company where in we give additional allowance based on their years of stay with the company.

My problem is I want to round down numbers if they are in between values. I created a formula where in their allowances are adjusted in a daily basis **eg. D(Date of Regularization), E(Today), F(No. of Years), G(increase), h(increase** per month).

There my letter "H" Column needs to be rounded down. For example our employee will be 2 years in 7 days. the allowance he receives (for now) should still be 50 (if two years it'll be 120), so what I want to do is if the value is between **50-119 it will round down into 50**, if the value is between **120-219 it will be 120** and so on..

```
(Years*Increase=Total)(1*50=50)(2*60=120)(3*70=210)(4*80=320)
```

I hope somebody will understand. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use `floor()` function for this? (Ceiling = value of higher end, round = nearest value, floor = value of lower end)

Comment: Help, can you give sample figures for this? Thanks!.. and is it possible if we can have multiple of this equation in one cell? For example... if the value is 50-119 it will be rounded down to 50, if not, if the value is 120-209 the value would be rounded down to 120, if not, if the value is 210-319 the value would be rounded down to 210 and so on...

Comment: Sorry, wrong suggestion about floor function, check my below answer for better solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sample formula

```
=IF(AND(A2>=50,A2<=119),"50",IF(AND(A2>=120,A2<=209),"120",IF(AND(A2>=210,A2<=319),"210")))
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlookup for this requirement.

Setup a reference table in some other part of the sheet, with the floor values you need:
E.g. This has been placed at [A2:A5]

```
50
120
210
320
```

Use the vlookup formula as below referring the values that you want to round-off. E.g.
`If C2 = 50, use =VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$5,1,TRUE), result will be 50`
`If C3 = 119, use =VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$5,1,TRUE), result will be 50`

NOTE: The last parameter in the vlookup is marked as `TRUE` so that it checks for approximate match and not exact match, which is the key for this solution.
You can also name the range for floor values and use that in the formulas.